# MongoDB array of objects query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

I have a database of users like this:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"name": "Carlo",
"cars": [{
    "type": "sport",
    "score": 10
}, {
    "type": "hatchback",
    "score": 5
}, {
    "type": "family",
    "score": 4
}, {
    "type": "family",
    "score": 3
}]
```

}

How can I choose all of the users whose hatchback has score more than 6?
So, query has to find in array of cars some object, which has a property 'type' with value 'hatchback' and 'score' more than 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to do this. here is a working sample

```
db.getCollection('users').find(
    {"cars": 
        {$elemMatch: 
            { "type": "hatchback","score": {$gte: 6}
            }
        }
    }
)
```

As you can see you the syntax of $elemMatch is

```
{ <field>: { $elemMatch: { <query1>, <query2>, ... } } }
```

Here your array field is "cars". 
Since you need match on type = hatchback and score greater than or equal to 6,
your query would be { "type": "hatchback","score": {$gte: 6}. Hope this helps.